# Flash size expands in IE8

Tags: html, xhtml, flash

I received a flash file from the design agency to incorporate on our template (Java/JSP based framework). I specified the width in the javascript flash player we have as those specified by the agency and 963x488, but in IE8 it seems the flash occupies more space than that and even though the flash content area remains small, the overall area occupied by flash is larger than the specified size. I tried the simple `<object>/<embed>` tags and it exhibits same behavior. Any idea if I can do something on the JSP or is it something that needs to be taken care of during creation of .swf file? I am running the latest plugin for flash and Firefox and Chrome do not have this issue.

Comment: Make sure that *zoom* is set to *100%* and *text size* to *Medium*. Under the *View* menu of IE8.

Comment: Yeah, that does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying that Flash's container is too big, right? That is, the area within which you can right-click and see a Flash context menu? If so, then your issue has nothing to do with the SWF content, plugin version, or Flash itself. The size of Flash's container is wholly determined by the HTML/CSS/JS of the embedding page, and browser behavior (like zooming, etc). So I think you'll need to post some details about the embedding code involved. You might also check against IE8 on other machines, in case there is a settings issue similar to what Alexandre commented about, though possibly involving different settings.

(The only exception, where the Flash content could be a factor, is if the Flash content is invoking a JS bridge to execute javascript calls to change the size of its own container. But even then it's still JS/HTML that has the say over container size.)

Comment: Alexandre was right. When I set zoom to 100% (it wasn't selected before), it rendered correctly.